# Is it bad idea to buy Condo because of low HOA fee

Tags: real-estate

Is it a bad idea to pick a condo to purchase because the HOA monthly fee is low?  Since they can raise it at any time I don't know if this is a criterion that should be considered as a major factor.  But it also has a huge impact on the monthly payments.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience if the builder/developer is still selling properties covered by the HOA the builder has an incentive to keep the HOA fee artificially low. The low HOA fee makes it easier to sell the properties.  Eventually as more of the complex/community is completed, the more seats on the board are occupied by homeowners.

After the developer is gone the elected board makes decisions related to the HOA budget. They want to balance the required costs, the desired options, and planning for the future. While nobody likes fees going up, the alternatives also make it hard to sell in the future. A closed pool, and overgrown common grounds aren't selling points.

Review the budget before you buy. They have to give you the budget and other documents before you are committed to the purchase. The budget will let you know what is being covered. The more amenities and common areas the higher the monthly fee has to be.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a black and white question, you have to consider the context of the particular condominium. Condos that offer a lot of features (earthquake insurance, elevators, swimming pool, gym, concierge, high end interior finishes in the common areas) will have higher HOA fees. Do you need or want those features?

On the other hand HOA fees can definitely be too low. They have to be at least high enough to keep the reserve fund topped up sufficiently to handle predictable maintenance costs. Many folks buy condos because they don't want to have to deal with property maintenance issues. The catch is that the maintenance still has to be done, you are just handing management of it to somebody else. Folks have a natural tendency to want to low-ball and put off maintenance costs, and this puts pressure on the HOA board to set a low monthly fee. This can come back to bite you when a massive special assessment becomes necessary to cover emergency repairs, or results in a gradual decline in the value of your unit.

Condo law varies quite a bit from state to state. In Washington state HOA are required to have a professional assessment of their reserve fund done periodically. The reserve assessment evaluates both the likely maintenance costs over time and the accumulation of funds in the reserve account to make sure the two match up.

Before buying a condo you should carefully review the latest reserve assessment (if available), the budgets and actual spending for the last few years, and the minutes of the HOA board meetings for the last few years. This is hopefully as boring as watching paint dry, but it can help shield you from nasty surprises. If you are looking at a unit in a larger condo (> 25 units say) and they can't provide those documents, that is in itself a flashing red light that the HOA is poorly managed. For smaller condos it's more ambiguous. The work will be handled entirely by the owners on the board without the backstop of a professional management company. The paperwork tends to fall behind, and you don't know whether it's because there are problems, or everybody on the board just had a really busy year.